# Run OpenGl program on remote server

Tags: x11, remote, opengl, xvfb

I often use X11 forwarding (occasionally VNC) to work on a remote machine, and this has worked great. But now I need to run a program that uses a specific version of OpenGL that means it doesn't work on OSX. I don't have root access to the remote headless machine, so I don't think I can use VirtualGL.

I have tried using Xvfb (and then x11vnc) but despite it saying the GLX extension is loaded when i run it. When I come to run any program that uses OpenGL, I get an error saying the display doesn't support GLX extension.

Is there any hope for getting this (mess of) software to to work together without having root access?